# different way of importing

Tags: python, numpy

Now what I am doing is:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(100)
```

is there anyway to import such that I could directly do:

```
x = arange(100)
```

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial, e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use all the `numpy` possibilities without prefix (`np`) :

```
from numpy import *
```

if you just want to use `arange()` :

```
from numpy import arange
```

Comment: The wildcard import `from numpy import *` is a **bad idea**, and [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says it "should be avoided" generally. It's particularly bad with `numpy`, as the namespace includes things like `all`, `min` and `random` that shadow built-ins and standard library modules, leading to subtle bugs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I now, but that's the only way i'm aware of to import entire numpy library without prefix. But you're right to notice it.

Answer (score 2):

```
from numpy import arrange
x = arange(100)
```